# Changing iPad Air 2 passcode with only having Touch ID

Tags: ipad

I just recently purchased an iPad Air 2 and when setting it up, I successfully created the fingerprint ID but cannot remember my actual passcode.  I can still access the iPad using Touch ID but is there a way I can change the passcode without knowing it?

Comment: There may be a way to do it using your Apple ID, but I don't remember off the top of my head. Whatever you do, do NOT restart your iPad or you won't be able to use Touch ID.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. There's no *easy* way to just change your passcode.

There is a way to reset your passcode, but it involves erasing your iPad. You may need to know your Apple ID password.

[Apple has steps here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306)

Those instructions basically involve going to iCloud.com or iTunes to erase your device. You then would be able to restore from a backup if need to.

I'm not sure if having Touch ID helps in any way. If you don't have a backup you can, possibly, use iTunes to make a backup first, unless it's brand new and you don't need to worry about restoring anything anyway.

Possibly you can just do erase all contents and settings in Settings > General > Reset and enter your Apple ID passcode too, but I'm not sure.

Whatever you do, avoid rebooting the iPad, because then TouchID will no longer work and you'll be forced to use the iCloud or iTunes erase and restore.

Comment: Thanks!  Its still pretty new and i havent added many things to it so a reboot is ok with me.  I know my Apple Id as well so that shouldnt be too dramatic.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to iTunes and make a backup, this can be done using touch ID. Then erase your iPad. Restore from Backup and I believe it will ask you to create a new PIN. It's not possible to access the passcode settings without actually knowing the passcode.